# Fuzzy Matching Duplicates in Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching, fuzzy-search

I have a `List<String[]>` of customer records in Java (from a database). I know from manually eyeballing the data that 25%+ are duplicates.

The duplicates are far from exact though. Sometimes they have different zips, but the same name and address. Other times the address is missing completely, etc...

After a day of research; I'm still really stumped as to how to even begin to attack this problem?

What are the "terms" that I should be googling for that describe this area (from a solve this in Java perspective)? And I don't suppose there is `fuzzymatch.jar` out there that makes it all just to easy?

Comment: Edit Distance algorithms such as Levenshtein Distance or Hamming Distance and possibly their derivations.

Comment: Lucerne and solr are written in java and feature tools for fuzzy matching, among other things.

Comment: Levenshtein's only going to work on a string though? Not a set of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done similar systems before for matching place information and people information. These are complex objects with many features and figuring out whether two different objects describe the same place or person is tricky. The way to do it is to break it down to the essentials.

Here's a few things that you can do:

0) If this is a oneoff, load the data into openrefine and fix things interactively. Maximum this solves your problem, minimum it will show you where your possible matches are.

1) there are several ways you can compare strings. Basically they differ in how reliable they are in producing negative and false matches. A negative match is when it matches when it shouldn't have. A positive match is when it should match and does. String equals will not produce negative matches but will miss a lot of potential matches due to slight variations. Levenstein with a small factor is a slightly better. Ngrams produce a lot of matches, but many of them will be false. There are a few more algorithms, take a look at e.g. the openrefine code to find various ways of comparing and clustering strings. Lucene implements a lot of this stuff in its analyzer framework but is a bit of a beast to work with if you are not very familiar with its design.

2) Separate the process of comparing stuff from the process of deciding whether you have a match. What I did in the past was qualify my comparisons, using a simple numeric score e.g. this field matched exactly (100) but that field was a partial match (75) and that field did not match at all. The resulting vector of qualified comparisons, e.g. (100, 75,0,25) can be compared to a reference vector that defines your perfect or partial match criteria. For example if first name, last name, and street match, the two records are the same regardless of the rest of the fields. Or if phonenumbers and last names match, that's a valid match too. You can encode such perfect matches as a vector and then simply compare it with your comparison vectors to determine whether it was a match, not a match, or a partial match. This is sort of a manual version of what machine learning does which is to extract vectors of features and then build up a probability model of which vectors mean what from reference data. Doing it manually, can work for simple problems.

3) Build up a reference data set with test cases that you know to match or not match and evaluate your algorithm against that reference set. That way you will know when you are improving things or making things worse when you tweak e.g. the factor that goes into Levinstein or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Jilles' answer is great and comes from experience. I've also had to work on cleaning up large messy tables and sadly didn't know much about my options at that time (I ended up using Excel and a lot of autofilters). Wish I'd known about OpenRefine.

But if you get to the point where you have to write custom code to do this, I want to make a suggestion as to how: The columns are always the same, right? For instance, the first String is always the key, the second is the First name, the sixth is the ZIP code, tenth is the fax number, etc.?

Assuming there's not an unreasonable number of fields, I would start with a custom Record type which has each DB field as member rather than a position in an array. Something like

```
class CustomerRow {
    public final String id;
    public final String firstName;
    // ...

    public CustomerRow(String[] data) {
        id = data[0];
        // ...
}
```

You could also include some validation code in the constructor, if you knew there to be garbage values you always want to filter out.

(Note that you're basically doing what an ORM would do automatically, but getting started with one would probably be more work than just writing the Record type.)

Then you'd implement some `Comparator<CustomerRow>`s which only look at particular fields, or define equality in fuzzy terms (there's where the edit distance algorithms would come in handy), or do special sorts.

Java uses a stable sort for objects, so to sort by e.g. name, then address, then key, you would just do each sort, but choose your comparators in the reverse order.

Also if you have access to the actual database, and it's a real relational database, I'd recommend doing some of your searches as queries where possible. And if you need to go back and forth between your Java objects and the DB, then using an ORM may end up being a good option.